# How can I write result of join in list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have dataframe like that

```
  key   A
0  K0  A0
1  K1  A1
2  K2  A2
3  K3  A3
4  K4  A4
5  K5  A5
```

and the other

```
  key   B
0  K0  B0
1  K1  B1
2  K2  B2
```

The result of `df.set_index('key').join(other.set_index('key'))` will be

```
      A    B
key
K0   A0   B0
K1   A1   B1
K2   A2   B2
K3   A3  NaN
K4   A4  NaN
K5   A5  NaN
```

I want to merge result of joining into one column which will contain list of corresponding values.
So I want to achieve the following:

```
      AB
key
K0   A0,B0
K1   A1,B1
K2   A2,B2
K3    A3
K4    A4
K5    A5
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframes `df` and `other` on `axis=0`, then `group` the resulting dataframe by `key` and aggregate column `A` using `','.join`:

```
c = pd.concat([df, other.rename(columns={'B': 'A'})])
df_out = c.groupby('key').agg(AB=('A', ','.join))
```

Alternatively, you can use `Series.map` to map the values in the `key` column in `df` with the values from the column `B` in `other`, then add column `A` with the mapped column `B` around the delimiter `,`:

```
B = df['key'].map(other.set_index('key')['B']).fillna('')
df_out = (df['A'] + ',' + B).str.rstrip(',').to_frame('AB')
```

---

```
>>> df_out

        AB
key       
K0   A0,B0
K1   A1,B1
K2   A2,B2
K3      A3
K4      A4
K5      A5
```

Comment: How can I use that in case `A` and `B` type is int?

Comment: Simply change the `dtype` of the columns before joining them. For example in case of `method 1` you can use `c.astype(str).groupby('key').agg(AB=('A', ','.join))`. For `method 2` you can use `(df['A'].astype(str) + ',' + B.astype(str)).str.rstrip(',').to_frame('AB')`